MSVC 2022 project committed returns a different sln file on checkout
As I was trying to upgrade one of my wxWidgets project to a newer release (3.2.2 - 3.2.5), I committed the local code to the local repo, then pushed the code to  central repo on my LAN.
When I clone a new copy from the LAN repo to my new working directory, I find that the vcxproj & sln files differed substantially. (in both the main project as well as in library sub-directory)
Using KDiff3 to compare the 'old' and newly cloned directories, I find that several files have differences I did not expect.
The most obvious ones are the sln and vcxproj files because the IDE finds these files as needing updates from MSVC Version 16 (MSVC 2029) to my currently installed version 17 (MSVC 2022)
Being a newb for anything beyond commit/clone/checkout I am totally lost as to why this issue cropped up and even more so how to 'fix it'.
Any explanation or help will most appreciated.
